# src/cpp/cuda.hpp:14:10: fatal error: cuda.h: No such file or directory

Tags: cuda, gpu, pycuda

when I install pycuda by this instruction:

```
pip install pycuda
```

but there is an error:

```
src/cpp/cuda.hpp:14:10: fatal error: cuda.h: No such file or directory
```

but I have installed the cuda toolkit.this is the result of nvcc -V

```
[root@localhost include]# nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jun_12_23:07:04_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.2, V9.2.148
```

this is the result of install rpm downloaded in https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

```
[root@localhost include]# sudo dnf install cuda
Last metadata expiration check: 0:05:09 ago on Wed 05 Sep 2018 10:08:35 PM EDT.
Package cuda-1:9.2.148.1-2.fc28.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to specify path to CUDA:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/include:${C_INCLUDE_PATH}
export LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64:$LIBRARY_PATH
```

Please make sure that `echo ${CUDA_HOME}` does provide some sensible output.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I have solved the problem of "cuda.h" . Now I have a new problem. 'error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1'. I have installed python-devel and python3-devel and cuda-devel etc.

Answer (score 17):

In my case I met both issues:

```
-lcurand not found
```

and

```
src/cpp/cuda.hpp:14:10: fatal error: cuda.h: No such file or directory
```

And exporting C_INCLUDE_PATH didn't helped me. Instead I needed to export general version of C_INCLUDE_PATH -- **CPATH**:

```
export CPATH=$CPATH:/usr/local/cuda/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

Answer (score 15):

This is how I solved the problem on Jetson NANO:

```
sudo pip3 install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/aarch64-linux/include/" --global-option="-L/usr/local/cuda-10.0/targets/aarch64-linux/lib/" pycuda
```

Comment: It also helped me compile on Jetson Xavier AGX. Only had to replace cuda-10.0 with cuda-10.2. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Related: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pycuda-installation-failure-on-jetson-nano/77152/22

Answer (score 4):

Find out where Cuda is installed on the system using 
`find / - type d - name cuda 2>/dev/null`

Use or which every location cuda is found on

`export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-VERSION/bin:$PATH`

Then

`pip install pycuda`

Comment: the `find` command listed all files for me, but this worked for me: `find / -name "*cuda*" -type d`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution that worked for me. This solution was taken from [here](https://alisonrowland.com/installing-pycuda-on-ubuntu-via-pip/).

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
$ pip install numpy
$ export CUDA_ROOT=/usr/local/cuda
$ pip install pycuda
```